# Android Studio Firebase Não inserindo dados

Tags: android-studio, firebase-database, realtime-database

Alguém sabe como inserir dados no Realtime database do Firebase?
Minha plicação não dá erros mas não insere nada no Firebase.

Obs.: Banco de dados e aplicativo estão conectados e sincronizados.

no Firebase, meu banco de dados é o buscacerto-inc. Quero criar uma árvore de dados, tipo:

```
buscacerto-inc
     |___users
           |___id
           |   |____Nome
           |   |____cpf
           |   |____email
           |
           |___id
               |____Nome
               |____cpf
               |____email
```

Meu código é o seguinte:

```
try{
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference refer = database.getReference("buscacerto-inc/users");
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario(email, senha); //Minha classe Usuario
    refer.push().setValue(usuario.pegaEmail(), usuario.pegaSenha());
    Toast.makeText(actCadastro.this, "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}catch (Exception ex){
    Toast.makeText(actCadastro.this, "Erro: " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Como eu disse, não gera erros e parece acessar o Firebase sem problemas. Estou usando Getters públicos (usuario.pegaEmail) para não deixar os campos da Classe expostos.
Usei o push() porque quero criar um id único para cada um.

Comment: Não precisa colocar "resolvido" no título. Sei que é prática comum em muitos fóruns, mas aqui é diferente. Vc já marcou uma resposta abaixo com ✔️ e isso é o suficiente para indicar que foi resolvido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Diogo**,
Muito obrigado pela sua resposta, mas devia ter alguma coisa errada em meu código/aplicativo porque eu criei um outro projeto do zero, conectei ao mesmo banco de dados da aplicação que estava dando problemas e funcionou.

Então eu fui nas configurações do Firebase do meu aplicativo que estava dando problemas e, na guia **Cloud Messaging**, apaguei todas as **Chaves do servidor**.

[image: Apagando Chave do servidor]

Depois disso, o próprio Firebase criou uma chave nova e o app conseguiu inserir novos usuários.

Obrigado Diogo.

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso o Cloud Firestore, nunca utilizei o Realtime Database. No meu caso fica:

```java
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Usuario usuario = new Usuario("Login","Password");
db.collection("usuarios")
                .add(usuario)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                        Toast.makeText(actCadastro.this, "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    Toast.makeText(actCadastro.this, "Falha ao cadastrar Usuario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                });
```

No Realtime database não deve ser muito diferente. Espero ter ajudado!